# wordpress get taxonomy list of custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am using "Video" theme for my wordpress website. In this theme, videos post type and "videoscategory" taxonomy are defined. Here is the register code for taxonomy:

```
add_action("init", "custom_posttype_menu_wp_admin1");
function custom_posttype_menu_wp_admin1()
{

 register_post_type('videos', 
            array('label' => __('Videos','templatic'),
                    'labels' => array(  'name' => __('Video','templatic'),
                                'singular_name' => __('Video','templatic'),
                                'add_new' => __('Add Video','templatic'),
                                'add_new_item'=> __('Add New Video','templatic'),
                                'edit' => __('Edit','templatic'),
                                'edit_item'=> __('Edit Video','templatic'),
                                'new_item' => __('New Video','templatic'),
                                'view_item' => __('View Video','templatic'),
                                'search_items' => __('Search Videos','templatic'),
                                'not_found' => __('No Videos found','templatic'),
                                'not_found_in_trash'=> __('No Videos found in trash','templatic')   
                               ),
                    'public'            => true,
                    'can_export'        => true,
                    'show_ui'           => true, // UI in admin panel
                    '_builtin'          => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in
                    '_edit_link'        => 'post.php?post=%d',
                    'capability_type'   => 'post',
                    'menu_icon'         => get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/favicon.ico',
                    'hierarchical'      => false,
                    'rewrite'           => array("slug" => "videos"), // Permalinks
                    'query_var'         => "videos", // This goes to the WP_Query schema
                    'supports'          => array(   'title',
                                                    'author', 
                                                    'excerpt',
                                                    'thumbnail',
                                                    'comments',
                                                    'editor', 
                                                    'trackbacks',
                                                    'custom-fields',
                                                    'revisions') ,
                    'show_in_nav_menus' => true ,
                    'taxonomies'        => array('videoscategory','videostags')
                )
            );
// Register custom taxonomy
register_taxonomy(  "videoscategory", 
            array(  "videos"    ), 
            array ( "hierarchical"=> true, 
                    "label"=> "Category", 
                    'labels'=> array(   'name' => __('Category','templatic'),
                             'singular_name'=> __('Category','templatic'),
                             'search_items'=> __('Search Category','templatic'),
                             'popular_items' => __('Popular Category','templatic'),
                              'all_items'=> __('All Category','templatic'),
                              'parent_item' => __('Parent Category','templatic'),
                              'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Category:','templatic'),
                              'edit_item' => __('Edit Category','templatic'),
                              'update_item'=> __('Update Category','templatic'),
                              'add_new_item'=> __('Add New Category','templatic'),
                              'new_item_name'=> __('New Make Category','templatic') ), 
                              'public'=> true,
                              'show_ui' => true,
                              'query_var'=> true,
                              "rewrite" => true 
 )
            );

}
```

I added some categories under videoscategory taxonomy. Now i want to get all the categories that belongs to videoscategory. I googled the whole day, and I use

```
$tax_terms =get_terms('videoscategory');
```

but get empty array. Does anyone know what is the problem? thanks.

Comment: Easy to get all custom post type category using: http://wp.me/p4esuX-3k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is use this code, you definitely find your solution

```
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby'       => 'term_id', 
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'    => true, 
);

$terms = get_terms('videoscategory', $cat_args);

    foreach($terms as $taxonomy){
         $term_slug = $taxonomy->slug;

    $tax_post_args = array(
          'post_type' => 'videos',
          'posts_per_page' => 999,
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'videoscategory',
                     'field' => 'slug',
                     'terms' => '$term_slug'
                )
           )
    );

    $tax_post_qry = new WP_Query($tax_post_args);

    if($tax_post_qry->have_posts()) :
         while($tax_post_qry->have_posts()) :
                $tax_post_qry->the_post();

                the_title();

          endwhile;

    else :
          echo "No posts";
    endif;
} //end foreach loop
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an example in the codex when you visit the [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) page

```
$terms = get_terms('videoscategory');
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo "<ul>";
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";

     }
     echo "</ul>";
 }
```

Just a tip: objects created under a custom taxonomy is called terms, not categories. Please see [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) I've done on WPSE

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for you that I used for a FAQ post type:

```
get_header();
if(have_posts()) {
    $args = array (
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    );
    $terms = get_terms( 'faq_levels', $args );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->slug;

        $post_args = array (
            'post_type'  => 'faq',
            'faq_levels' => $term->name,
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $post_args );
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post(); ?>
```

and I created the post type like this:

```
function post_type_faqs() {
    register_post_type('faq', array(
        'label'=>'FAQ',
        'menu_icon' => '',
        'labels'=>array(
            'name'=>_x('FAQs', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name'=>_x('FAQ', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new'=>_x('Add New', 'faq'),
            'add_new_item'=>__('Add New FAQ'),
            'edit_item'=>__('Edit FAQ'),
            'new_item'=>__('New FAQ'),
            'view_item'=>__('View FAQ'),
            'search_items'=>__('Search FAQs'),
            'not_found'=>__('No faqs found'),
            'not_found_in_trash'=>__('No faqs found in Trash'),
            'parent_item_colon'=>''),
        'public'=>true,
        'publicly_queryable'=>true,
        'show_ui'=>true,
        'query_var'=>true,
        'rewrite'=>false,
        'capability_type'=>'post',
        'supports'=>array('title','thumbnail','post-formats'),
        'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag','faq_category'),
        'slug'=>'faq',
        'hierarchical'=>false,
        'menu_position'=>6,
        'show_in_nav_menus'=> true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'faq_add_meta_boxes'

    ));
}
add_action('init', 'post_type_faqs');

/**
 * Create Subjects taxonomy
 */
function faq_category() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'dc' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'dc' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Categories', 'dc' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Categories', 'dc' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Category', 'dc' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Category:', 'dc' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Category', 'dc' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Category', 'dc' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Category', 'dc' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Category', 'dc' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate categories with commas', 'dc' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Categories', 'dc' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove categories', 'dc' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used categories', 'dc' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'dc' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'sort_column'                => 'menu_order',

    );
    register_taxonomy( 'faq_category', array( 'faq' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'faq_category', 0 );
```