# get_terms WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )

Tags: php, wordpress

How to solve WP_Error Object  for get_terms function ? 
I registered custom taxonomy `tax_alone_event` at the `coustom-post-type.php` file.
and include at the `functions.php` file.
Here is my code

```
function get__terms_list() {
  $terms = get_terms('tax_alone_event');
  return $terms ;

} //End get_terms_list()..

print_r(get__terms_list());
```

And I register custom post and custom taxonomy code at `coustom-post-type.php` file

```
function Alone_setup_post_type_project() {
    // event custom post and tax 
    $alone_event_args = array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'               => _x( 'Event', 'post type general name', 'alonefoundation' ),
             'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Event', 'alonefoundation' ),
             'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Event', 'alonefoundation' ),
             'new_item'           => __( 'New Event', 'alonefoundation' ),
             'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Event', 'alonefoundation' ),
             'view_item'          => __( 'View Event', 'alonefoundation' ),
             'all_items'          => __( 'All Event', 'alonefoundation' ),
        ),
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'alonefoundation' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'event' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'taxonomies'            => array('tax_alone_event'),
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
    );
    register_post_type( 'alone-event', $alone_event_args );
    $alone_event_tax = array(
        'label' => __( 'Category' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event_tax' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    ) ;
    register_taxonomy( 'tax_alone_event', array('alone-event'), $alone_event_tax );
}

add_action( 'init', 'Alone_setup_post_type_project');
```

Answer (score 3):

The `get_terms()` function will only show the default `WordPress taxonomies` unless you hook it to init.

```
function get__terms_list() {
  $terms = get_terms('tax_alone_event',array(
    'hide_empty' => false
 ));
  print_r($terms);
} //End get_terms_list()..

//print_r(get__terms_list());

add_action('init','get__terms_list');
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
[0] => WP_Term Object ( 
[term_id] => 28 
[name] => Custom Taxonomy 
[slug] => custom-taxonomy 
[term_group] => 0 
[term_taxonomy_id] => 28 
[taxonomy] => tax_alone_event 
[description] => 
[parent] => 0 
[count] => 0 
[filter] => raw )
 )
```

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: I just have run this code on my local machine. It working fine.

Comment: @MamunurRashid, As I understood, you are trying to get all categories lists right?

Comment: @MamunurRashid, Did you include `coustom-post-type.php` file in functions.php file?

Comment: yes I include `coustom-post-type.php` file in `functions.php` file..  I am trying to get all categories/taxonomy for specific custom post  `alone_event`

Comment: Please see this solution. Hope it will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563809/wordpress-get-taxonomy-list-of-custom-post-type

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of errors in two ways

1. don't use `init` hook, directly call `Alone_setup_post_type_project()`;
2. use `get_terms` function also with init hook

because what you are doing is that using `get_terms` function before wordpress has registered your post type and taxonomy with the system and thus unable to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass taxonomies via the 'taxonomy' argument in the `$args` array from 4.5.0 - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/.

```
function get__terms_list() {
    $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'tax_alone_event' ) );
    return $terms ;
}

print_r(get__terms_list());
```

Comment: thank you for your comment .

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: see this screenshot =>  http://prntscr.com/kc18hy

Comment: This might help - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29150/why-is-my-working-custom-taxonomy-not-in-get-taxonomies-array.

Comment: Also you should call taxonomy registration function in separate `init` function.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code to myself and it works well.
In which file do you have this part?

```
function get__terms_list() {
  $terms = get_terms('tax_alone_event');
  return $terms ;

} //End get_terms_list()..

print_r(get__terms_list());
```

`print_r(get__terms_list());` should be in file like page.php, footer.php, etc.

Put `print_r(get_taxonomies());` before `print_r(get__terms_list());` to see if your taxonomy is registered.